# How to active html element when clicked on it in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

When I click on any html element, I want to it to remain active, Please see the demo, In following demo, if I clicked on any inactive html, then it becomes active, or vise-versa.
[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UGxmVynROpvkZmamKfI5?p=preview)

```
  <div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <a title="week? category" ng-model="week" class="tag">week</a>
    <a title="week? category" ng-model="month" class="tag">month</a>
    <a title="week? category"  ng-model="year" class="tag">year</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `ng-class` to set a class in your DOM on click so also need to use `ng-click` to call a function to set active menu. No need to use `ng-model` in anchor tag.

Can try it

In HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'week'}" ng-click="makeActive('week')">week</a>
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'month'}" ng-click="makeActive('month')">month</a>
        <a title="week? category"  class="tag" ng-class="{selected:selectedType == 'year'}" ng-click="makeActive('year')">year</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

in Controller:

```
$scope.selectedType= '' ;// initially empty 

$scope.makeActive = function(getName) {
   $scope.selectedType = getName;
}
```

and in css: add another class selected

```
.tag:hover, .selected {
      background-color: red;
      border-color: red;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to have a scope variable that will save which button is clicked (via the `ng-click` attribute) and to conditionally assign a `css` class (via the `ng-class` attribute) to the matching link.

Html file:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <div class="wrapper col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <!-- 
         when you click the link, it will set $scope.type to the define type
         ('week' in the first case), 
         we then compare $scope.type with some hardcoded value to set the
         class and change the css properties accordingly) 
         Of course, you could extract this to a $scope method
    -->
    <a title="week? category" ng-class="{active: vm.type=='week'}" ng-click="vm.type = 'week'" class="tag">week</a>
    <a title="week? category" ng-class="{active: vm.type=='month'}" ng-click="vm.type = 'month'" class="tag">month</a>
    <a title="week? category"  ng-class="{active: vm.type=='year'}" ng-click="vm.type = 'year'" class="tag">year</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.type = null;
});
```

Css (for the `active` class):

```
.tag:hover, .active {
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}
```

See [Forked plknr](http://plnkr.co/edit/k8EQteEZC0R1V81Orpdb?p=preview)